# Normal not working with Translate and some Graphics object

Tags: graphics, conversion, geometric-transform

in v13, `Normal` doesn't seem to work with `Translate` and some Graphics objects like `Rectangle` and `Circle`.

Is this known issue? [doc page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html?view=all) says "if possible" - why wouldn't it be in the following examples?

> Normal[expr] if possible replaces all Translate[gi,…] constructs by
> versions of the gi in which the coordinates have explicitly been
> transformed.

Examples:

```
Normal@Translate[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], {3, 4}]

Normal@Translate[Circle[{0, 0}], {3, 4}]
```

Comment: I checked on v12.2 and it doesn't work there either, so this is not specific or new to v13 it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to assign [`UpValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) to [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Before

```
Normal@Translate[
  Circle[{xc, yc}], {x0, y0}]

(* Translate[Circle[{xc, yc}], {x0, y0}] *)

Normal@Translate[
  Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}], {x0, y0}]

(* Translate[Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}], {x0, y0}] *)
```

Add `UpValues`

```
Unprotect[Translate];

Translate /: Normal@Translate[
    Circle[{xc_, yc_}, r_ : 1], {x0_, y0_}] :=
  Circle[{xc + x0, yc + y0}, r];

Translate /: Normal@Translate[
    Rectangle[{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}], {x0_, y0_}] :=
  Rectangle[{xmin + x0, ymin + y0}, {xmax + x0, ymax + y0}];

Protect[Translate];
```

After

```
Normal@Translate[Circle[{xc, yc}], {x0, y0}]

(* Circle[{x0 + xc, y0 + yc}, 1] *)

Normal@Translate[Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}], {x0, y0}]

(* Rectangle[{x0 + xmin, y0 + ymin}, {x0 + xmax, y0 + ymax}] *)
```